# How to play encrypted dvds on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dvd

I am trying to play a movie on ubuntu and it will not work. It tells me that I need to install dvd decryption. I was researching online and found out that I need to install libdvdread4, I did that. I also read that I needed to install libdvdcss, and this is where there was a problem. I ran:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh into the terminal and got the following:

--2013-10-10 20:52:33--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/free/binary-i386/Packages
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.127.22
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.127.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-10-10 20:52:33 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Dynamic fetch failed; Falling back to static fetch
--2013-10-10 20:52:33--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.2medibuntu1_i386.deb
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.127.22
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.127.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

I am wondering if there is any other way to install libdvdcss.
Thanks

Comment: The bug is now fixed, updating and trying the script again should now work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NB:** This software may be illegal in your jurisdiction due to intellectual property laws. Use at your own risk.

The script was trying to pull a package from the [Medibuntu Project](http://www.medibuntu.org/), which has been [discontinued](https://launchpad.net/medibuntu/+announcement/11951).

You can try installing `libdvdcss` from [Videolan's website](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://packages.medibuntu.org is gone. The packages have been removed because there was no one to maintain them. Videolan still maintains these files in deb packaging. You can find libdvdcss2  here  http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/1.2.10/deb/. You will need to search for the rest but they are there